# How to reconfigure for new hardware after cloning from a desktop to a laptop?

Tags: hardware

After cloning a hard drive (with Ubuntu 10.04) to a new computer, how can I configure the OS to its new hardware?

What I've done so far:

1. Clone desktop HDD to laptop HDD
2. run `boot-repair` to fix the GRUB setup on laptop HDD
3. edit `/etc/fstab` to list the laptop HDD's UUID
4. enter wlan0 as the wireless adapter in the network manager, to get wireless back up.

When I boot, a window pops up saying:

> Ubuntu is running in low-graphics mode.
>
> The following error was encountered. You may need to update your configuration to solve this.
>
> (EE) No devices detected.

In the subsequent dialog I choose "Run Ubuntu in low-graphics mode for just one session", and the boot proceeds without any further error messages. However, some problems remain:

- The monitor resolution is wrong; the correct resolution isn't available in the Monitors control panel.
- The headphone jack doesn't seem to work.

Are there some commands I can run which automatically reconfigure the hardware setup, like the Ubuntu installer does?

(You may be wondering why I did this, instead of simply installing Ubuntu on my laptop from a CD, then copying over my desktop's home directory. My workplace desktop uses a particular proxy setup for wired internet connections, which I won't be able to replicate from a fresh Ubuntu install.)

**EDIT:** I have since gotten the wireless back up; I just had to enter "wlan0" into the network-manager's box for wireless interfaces.

Comment: @EliahKagan I think I've misled a lot of people by even referring to what I use as a "custom distro". It is Ubuntu 10.04. The only thing different is that it uses a particular network proxy setup for wired ethernet using cntlm. This has nothing to do with the scope of the question, namely how to fix my graphics, wireless internet, and in general how to re-run the config scripts used by the installer. I'm edited the question to be less confusing. Could it be re-opened?

Comment: @EliahKagan Ok thank you. Following your suggestion, I posted to meta about this question (http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5575). How do I flag it for moderator attention?

Comment: This may work, http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ubuntu-tiphow-to-removeinstall-and-reconfigure-xorg-without-reinstalling-ubuntu.html

Comment: Is this still reproducible?